# Redirect user to the App/Play Store or the App itself

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-play, app-store

I do a check to see if the device they are using is an Android or an Apple device. I then want to check if the application is installed, if it is, we go into the app, otherwise, we go into the App/Play Store for the specific application.

```
window.location.href = 'mydeeplink://www.URL.com/'
```

This should work by going into the play store...

```
window.location.href = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ID_OF_APP'
```

However, how can I check with `mydeeplink` is valid, or this routed to the app, before I push the user to the app store?

Originally I had them right after each other, that didn't work... what is the better way?

Comment: Have you looked at Google's Firebase Dynamic Links, it's free and handles these issues for you - https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links

Comment: @RyanSparks I did. I added my DNS but Google still hasn't found it. So waiting on it to see what happens